# when i clicking the button the SignIn.html is added to current path but it doesnot opens the SignIn.html

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.go = function() {
    $location.url('SignIn.html');
    $location.replace();
};


<button ng-click="go()"></button>
```

when i clicking the button the SignIn.html is added to current path but it doesnot opens the SignIn.html

Comment: try $window.url - but why aren't you using ngRoute for your routing??

Comment: i tried with $window.url  but the same thing will be done in the new window there is no change. And I want make this navigation will be done when an ng-click event raised. So i am writing this one

Answer (score 1):

In order to redirect the page, you can use `$location.path("/route");` as following:

```
$scope.go=function() {
    $location.path("/SignIn.html");
};
```

Note: Don't forget to inject `$location` into controller.